# Python and condition a<b and a<c the same as a<b and c

Tags: python, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

I get the same results for the condition:

```
a<b and a<c
```

and the condition:

```
a<b and c
```

`a`, `b`, `c` are variables of the type `float`

I never see that before. I prefer the first writing way. I only forgot a< in my code. But it is working.

Is it possible in python to short the condition like that? Is there a special name for shortcuts like that above?

Thank you for an answer in advance!
Yours
JoeJoe

Comment: What are the values of `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: It's not, but it happens to work for some values of `a`, `b` and `c` that you're trying it with. It worked because non-0 floats are truthy. Consider a trivial counter example: `-1 < 1 and 0` (`a = -1; b = 1; c = 0`)

Comment: They are different and this is a common pitfall: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false